# Scala class casting

Tags: scala, class, casting, implicit

I have:

```
var className = "scala.collection.immutable.List"
val clazz = Class.forName(className)
val value = ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3)
```

so the question is how to cast value to class, if className is variable? I can't do

```
value.asInstanceOf[clazz.type]
```

but i can call

```
value.toList
```

and it does the job with implicit conversion method, but how i can find and invoke this method when className is variable?

Comment: Parameter in `asInstanceOf` can't be represented with a variable, it's a compile-time entity. `clazz.type` value OTOH only exists at runtime.

Comment: Thanx, cap. The question is how to cast ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3) to List at runtime when i have only className...

Comment: I don't think it is wise what you are doing but here it is: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast(java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a magical way to convert from `ArrayBuffer` to any collection, but you can call `getMethod` to locate and invoke the `toList` method:

```
val method = value.getClass.getMethod("toList")
method.invoke(value)
```

An exception will be thrown if `toList` in not found in value. I would have preferred to comment my answer, but not enough reputation